# how to get regular blinking on a automatically refreshing div

Tags: javascript, html, blink

I am working on making a webpage that displays multiple temperatures. When a temperature value goes out of limits (too hot/cold) its background blinks red.

The way I've gotten it to work so far, is that a python script generates text files that include temperature values. Text from temperature files are then loaded into the html script via div's that automatically refresh at 5 second intervals. When temperature level is out of range, a string of code is included in the text file which makes the div blink.

**Main Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Temperatures</title>
<style>

body {
    background-color: grey;
}

.backgroundRed{
    background: red;
}

#container
{
    height:550px;
    width:400px;
    position:absolute;
}

#image
{    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0px;
}

#Temp01
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:black;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:40px;
    top:35px;
}
#Temp02
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:black;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:40px;
    top:145px;
}
#Temp03
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:black;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:40px;
    top:255px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="room.jpg"/>
    <div id="Temp01">
    </div>
    <div id="Temp02">
    </div>
    <div id="Temp03">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function(){
$('#Temp01').load('Temp01.txt');
refreshTemp01();
});
function refreshTemp01()
{
 setTimeout( function() {
   $('#Temp01').load('Temp01.txt');
   refreshTemp01();
 }, 5000);
}

$(document).ready( function(){
$('#Temp02').load('Temp02.txt');
refreshTemp02();
});
function refreshTemp02()
{
 setTimeout( function() {
   $('#Temp02').load('Temp02.txt');
   refreshTemp02();
 }, 5000);
}

$(document).ready( function(){
$('#Temp03').load('Temp03.txt');
refreshTemp03();
});
function refreshTemp03()
{
 setTimeout( function() {
   $('#Temp03').load('Temp03.txt');
   refreshTemp03();
 }, 5000);
}

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

**Temp01.txt:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var backgroundInterval = setInterval(function(){
    $("#Temp01").toggleClass("backgroundRed");
 },1000)
</script>

25.5degC
```

It works, but the blinks are too irregular (because of the div's automatic refreshing). Can anyone think of a way to create a toggle or something that makes all the out of limit temperatures blink at a regular interval? Note that the divs don't blink until they are out of range because python creates a text file with plain text (no script) when they are within range

**Temp02.txt:**

Comment: So much repeated code...

Comment: You may want to read about requestAnimationFrame API.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I'll google requestAnimationFrame API tomorrow.